# Developing Android applications on a shared server

Tags: android, adb, ddms

We are trying to use a shared server (Ubuntu 9.10 64-bit) to develop Android applications. The thought is that a number of developers should use the shared server for development. We have overcome some obstacles such as setting the base port for DDMS. So it is possible to run multiple emulators and multiple instances of Eclipse.

But we run into problems when trying to debug applications from Eclipse. It seems as though all emulators are trying to connect to the same Eclipse instance when debugging.

Has anyone succeeded with this?

I know that this is a really bad idea, but I need to gather facts in order to have a strong case...

Comment: you should use a scm instead!

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an absolutely horrible idea.  Each developer should have their own instance of Java, Eclipse and the Android SDK installed on their local machines.  To work on the same project simply share the project via a [Source Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) solution which resides on a shared server [(CVS/SVN/Git)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software).

Comment: I know, that's my opinion also, but the desicion is unfortunately not in my hands. I need to give some facts about why it cannot be done...

Comment: How about giving them the fact that you're going to run into horrible port issues and stuff, and you're going to be overwriting each other's file changes with no visibility into what was changed in any sort of merge view.  How about giving them the fact that everyone else in the world does it the way I described above, because after many years of dealing with this problem that is what everybody decided was the best solution.

All these tools (Java, Eclipse, Android SDK, and CVS or SVN or Git) are all free, so there is no advantage to doing it the way you are now, and tons of disadvantages.

Comment: Sorry for not beeing clear. 
On the shared server everyone will have their Eclipse workspaces and the sourcecode in their own home directories. The Android SDK will also reside in the users home directory on the server. The code will be managed via Git/repo/Gerrit. So the SCM part is not an issue. 
The port issues are the real problem here. But it's bad enough...

Comment: I'd be interested to know why you are trying to develop that way.  I still recommend just developing via local machines.

Comment: As I said, it's not my decision so I cannot answer the question why... I have not been a part of the decision making process. My opinion is the same as yours.